# Why does sound travel in a wave?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, visible-light, acoustics

Sound waves carry energy. Why does sound travel in a wave instead of a straight line when travelling in a wave covers more distance and is less energy-efficient than travelling in a straight line? This question may also apply to other electromagnetic waves like light and x-rays.

In addition, what will happen if ,like light, sound is a particle , will we still hear anything?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: *travel in a wave instead of a straight line* I think you’ve seen a graph of a sinusoidal wave and erroneously believe that it means sound moves “up and down” while moving outward. The graph of a sound wave is actually showing higher and lower air pressure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does sound travel in a wave instead of a straight line ?

The waves that make up sound are [longitudinal waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitudinal_wave). The wave itself does travel in a straight line (in an isotropic medium) and the individual molecules in the medium move back and forth.

> This question may also apply to electromagnetic waves ...

Electromagnetic radiation also travels in a straight line (in an isotropic medium). The waves that make up electromagnetic radiation are varying intensities of electric and magnetic fields. These verying intensities are represented by the sinusoidal graphs that you probably have in mind when you picture a wave.

> What will happen if, like light, sound is a particle ?

Sound can indeed behave like a particle. When it does, it is called a [phonon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonon).